# Using promises with Node.js functions on example

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm started learning JavaScript promises, but I can't understand how apply, for example, Q functions to Node.js callback functions.

[In similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351494/promises-pattern-in-node-js-libraries-to-use) is recommended to use `Q.denodeify()`, but it works well for `fs.readFile()` and don't works for `fs.exists()`.

This is a simple functions that returns list of files and their sizes in directory:

```
function openDir(path, callback) {
    path = __dirname + path;
    fs.exists(path, function (exists) {
        if (exists) {
            fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                var filesCounter = 0,
                    filesTotal = files.length,
                    result = [];
                files.forEach(function (filename, index) {
                    fs.stat(path + filename, function (err, stats) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                        result[index] = {};
                        result[index].name = filename;
                        result[index].size = stats.size;
                        if (++filesCounter === filesTotal) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
}

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    openDir('/', function (data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        });
        res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

How write this code using promises (with [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or other library)?

Comment: You could take a look at my gist, which uses pretty similar tasks and it's written with Q https://gist.github.com/riston/9022931.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fs.exists is kind of a useless method.  It does not return a node style call back and can usually be omitted.  In your example you would handle the error from `fs.readdir`.

> fs.exists() is an anachronism and exists only for historical reasons.
>   There should almost never be a reason to use it in your own code.
>   [node docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback)

Here is your example reworked with Q, note that we defer error handling to the caller by returning a promise instead of the stats themselves. I included an example of how to handle fs.exists with Q.defer to show how you can proxy non node style callbacks.

```
var Q = require('q'); 
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var readdir = Q.denodeify(fs.readdir);

function stat(file){
    return Q.nfcall(fs.stat, file)
        .then(function(stats){
            stats.filename = file;
            return stats;
        });
}

function openDir(path) {
    path = __dirname + path;

    return readdir(path)
        .then(function(files) { 
            return files.map(function(file){ 
                return stat(path + file); }); })
        .then(Q.all);
};

// proxy fs.exists to return a promise. Example of Q.defer
function exists(file){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    fs.exists(file, function(result){
        return result ? deferred.resolve(file) : deferred.reject('invalid file');    
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    openDir('/').done(
        function (data) {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
            res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        function (err) {
            res.writeHead(500, {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
            res.end(JSON.stringify({error: err}));
        });
    }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```